# VLC plays a video black and white

Tags: video, vlc

I have an MTS file recorded from my Lumix GX1. Before I reinstalled OSX 10.8 I could play these videos fine in VLC, however now they're in black and white (not greyscale, just black or white).

When I upload them to YouTube they seem fine! What codec am I missing?

Comment: Problem is Video Effects wont open... ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Came across my video effects that I had set in VLC. If mine were enable, the picture was black and white, as in, sharp black and white. I disabled them and the picture was back to normal. Try messing with them to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

These steps solved the problem for me:

1. Go to Tools → Preferences.
2. At the bottom, click Reset Preferences, then Yes.
3. Close VLC and reopen it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I've edited your answer to attempt to distil the essence of the solution, but feel free to edit further if you feel I've removed critical information.